# how many trials of independent event with probability p needed to reach chance q of at least one success

Tags: probability

Given an independent event with probability $p$ and a number of trials $k$, if I want there to be a probability of at least $q$ that the event has occurred at least once, how big does $k$ have to be in terms of $p$ and $q$?

As a concrete example:
An event could be I have a bag of $10$ balls with only $1$ blue ball and my event is to randomly pick a ball out of the bag and check if it is blue. (then return the ball)
I would like to fix upfront the maximum number of attempts I will do but I want at least an $80%$ chance of picking the blue ball in at least one of my attempts. 
It's been a while since I did any probability but here are some of my starting thoughts..

If I wanted a $10\%$ chance then I would simply choose one trial $(p=0.1,q=0.1,k=1)$
However no finite number of trials could give me $100\%$ chance.

Looking at it the other way I can see that if I have three trials then the probablility of getting at least one success is $0.1 + (0.9)(0.1) + (0.9)(0.9)(0.1) = 0.1 + 0.09 + 0.081 = 0.271$
(or look at it as $p + (1-p)p + p(1-p)^2$ - I'm rusty on how to write that for any k but know it's simple enough.)

I have looked at the question [Calculating number of independent trials needed for event to occur at least n times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215536/calculating-number-of-independent-trials-needed-for-event-to-occur-at-least-n-ti) , which seems to me to be a more general form of the problem where there must be $n$ number of successes, so I'm hoping with $n$ fixed at 1 the answer is simpler.

Comment: Many thanks drhab and DylanSp I've upvoted but my reputation is too low for this to be publicly shown yet.

Comment: You can choose to accept the answer that helped you most; click the check mark to the left of the answer's text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the event that  we want to occur be $X$. Then for $k$ trials, $P(X = 0) = (1 - p)^{n}$. $P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X = 0)$, so to find $k$ for a desired total chance of $q$, we have 
\begin{align*}
q &= P(X \geq 1) \\
q &= 1 - P(X = 0) \\
q &= 1 - (1 - p)^{k} \\
(1 - p)^{k} &= 1 - q \\
k &= \log_{(1 - p)} (1 - q) \\
k &= \frac{\ln (1 - q)}{\ln (1 - p)}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the event will *not* occur in $k$ trials is $(1-p)^k$.

So to be found is a least value for $k$ such that: $$1-(1-p)^k\geq q$$
Working this out we find that $k$ is the least positive integer that satisfies:$$k\geq\frac{\log(1-q)}{\log(1-p)}$$