# Asymptotics of partial exponential sum $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{a n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

The question [Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{-n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n^k}{k!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/) has been [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297553/how-to-compute-lim-n-rightarrow-inftye-n-left1n-fracn22-cdots-f?noredirect=1&lq=1) [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136996/partial-sums-of-exponential-series) [times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121099/) here, and there are different approaches for answering it.

Motivated by [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328198/asymptotic-gilbert-varshamov-bound-using-hilberts-entropy-formula), I'm interested in how to attack the modified problem where the number of terms grows as a fraction of $n$. I.e. the behaviour  of

$$S(n;a) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{an} \frac{n^k}{k!}$$

for large $n$, with fixed $a \in (0,1)$ (the upper limit of the summation is understood to be taken as the nearest integer).

Or more specifically,

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{an} \frac{n^k}{k!} \right)^{1/n}$$

Comment: Notice that $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^{an} \frac{n^k}{k!} = \frac{e^n \Gamma (a n+1,n)}{\Gamma (a n+1)}$. I am not quite sure if this will help.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, the problem is that (if I'm not mistaken) the probability (that in the original problem corresponded to half the gaussian curve) now corresponds to a vanishing tail, with probability tending to zero - and it becomes more problematic to use the CLT (as $n$ grows, the $z$ value of the normalized CDF decreases...)

Comment: Are you saying that the last limit does not depend on $a$ ? I'm not sure about that, because $f(a)$ tends to zero (as $n$ grows) for fixed $a<1$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I've worked out an answer (not rigorous, but it looks right numerically), unless I'm mistaken the limit definitely depends on $a$.

Comment: Using the convergence of the Poisson distribution to the normal distribution for large parameters,

$$ e^{-n}\sum_{k\leq an}\frac{n^k}{k!}=\mathbb{P}[\text{Pois}(n)\leq an]\to\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{N}(n,n)\leq an]=\int_{-\infty}^{an}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}e^{-\frac{(x-n)^2}{2n}}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\left[1+\text{Erf}\left((a-1)\sqrt{n/2}\right)\right]$$
so I would expect
$$ \sqrt[n]{\sum_{k\leq an}\frac{n^k}{k!}}\to \exp\left(1-\frac{(1-a)^2}{2}\right)$$
for any $a\in(0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's my (not very rigorous) try. Other approaches or refinements are welcomed.

Let's change notation $m = a n$, $x = n  = mb$ with $b = 1/a$.

Then $$e^x =  \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{x^k}{k!} + R_m(x) \tag1$$

with the remainder:

$$
\begin{align}
R_m(x) &= \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^m}{m!} e^t dt\\
&=\frac{e^x}{m!}\int_0^x y^m e^{-y} dt\\
&=\frac{e^x}{m!} \left(m!- \int_x^\infty y^m e^{-y} dt\right) \tag2\\
\end{align}
$$

Because $b>1$, we can approximate the complement of the gamma integral by [abusing Laplace's method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234358/asymptotics-justification-for-abusing-laplaces-method). Namely, for a differentiable positive decreasing function (more in general, a function that has its global maximum at the start of the interval of integration) and for $m\to \infty$ we approximate

$$ \int_c^\infty e^{m h(x)}dx\approx \int_c^\infty e^{m [h(c) + h'(c)(x-c)]}dx=\frac{e^{m \, h(c)}}{m \,|h'(c)|} \tag{3}$$

Then we can write 
$$
\int_x^\infty y^m e^{-y} dt =\int_x^\infty e^{m (\log(y)-y/m)}  \approx x^m e^{-x} \frac{b}{b-1} \tag 4\\
$$

Actually we are abusing the method here because our $h()$ depends also on $m$ - this would need some justification. Passing over this and putting all together:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{x^k}{k!}  &= e^x - R_m(x) \\
& \approx \frac{x^m}{m!} \frac{b}{b-1} \\ \tag{5}
&= \frac{n^{an}}{(an)!} \frac{1}{1-a} \\
& \approx \left(\frac{e}{a}\right)^{an} \frac{1} {(1-a) \, \sqrt{ 2 \pi a} \, \sqrt{n}}   \tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

Finally

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{an} \frac{n^k}{k!} \right)^{1/n}= \left(\frac{e}{a}\right)^a \tag 7$$

---

Added: As rightly comments @Maxim, if we are interested in correcting the rounding (when $m$ in $(5)$ is not an integer we round down to the nearest integer), we should multiply $(6)$ by the correction factor $a^{\{an\}}$,
where $\{\}$ denotes the fraction part. Of course, this correction is asymptotically negligible ($O(1)$) and does not change the limit $(7)$.

Comment: If $m = n/b \in \mathbb N$, then
$$\sum_{k = 0}^m \frac {(b m)^k} {k!} =
\frac {e^{b m} \Gamma(m + 1, b m)} {\Gamma(m + 1)} =
\frac {(b m)^{m + 1} e^{b m}} {\Gamma(m + 1)}
 \int_1^\infty e^{m (-b t + \ln t)} dt \sim
\frac {b (e b)^m} {(b - 1) \sqrt {2 \pi m}}.$$
The last term in the sum is not negligible, so it appears that without the assumption $a n \in \mathbb N$, we'll get
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor a n \rfloor} \frac {n^k} {k!} \sim
\left( \frac e a \right)^{a n}
 \frac {a^{\{a n\}}} {(1 - a) \sqrt {2 \pi a n}}.$$