# Formula for Combinatorial expression

Tags: combinatorics

Is there some combinatorial identity or formula for the following sum?

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^{k} \dbinom{n}{i}$$

All I could find on the internet was for $$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \dbinom{n}{i}$$

Comment: Nothing particularly nice.  [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n) includes some bounds.  As does [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103280/asymptotics-for-a-partial-sum-of-binomial-coefficients)